# Get vertex data from GLSL to program itself

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am using vertex displacement in glsl vertex shader. Example:

```
vertex = inVertex; // "layout in" parameter.
map_data = texture( heightMap, uv );
float displacement = u_map_scale * map_data.r;
vertex.y += displacement;
gl_Position = MVP * vertex;
```

Creating the terrain in main program code like that:

```
for( x < sizeW ..... )
{ 
    for( y < sizeH ..... ) {
    m_buffer[nIndex] = Vector3( xData, 0.0f, zData );
    .....
```

Notice that, Y(height) parameter is 0.0. Problem is in collision detection: actually, when it returns 'm_buffer[nIndex].y' for its height value, it equals 0, because height value is generated in glsl.

So the question itself:
How can I get vertex data back from glsl and bind it back to my buffer data, m_buffer?

Comment: you could use [transform feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback)

Comment: idk in what context you're using this - but if it is something that does not change, like a terrain, I'd consider dropping the vertex shader displacement completely - no point in performing a constant displacement every frame. compute the displaced geometry on the cpu, and the collision detection problem is gone. otherwise, yeah, transform feedbacks could help.

Comment: Well, I will try to do this. Because when I do calculations on CPU it looks weird.

Comment: I will use Transform Feedback. But I am afraid about performance, because I need to render large terrain.

Comment: @NekoCode: You really shouldn't worry about performance. You store the results of transform feedback in a buffer object. That means the memory stays on the GPU the entire time. You never have to read anything back from GL or anything like that, so it's very efficient compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for useful information! Now I am going to use transform feedback definitely! "Solved"!